# Where would I ask about home audio setup?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm thinking of getting a mac mini, which only supports 5.1 sound using its optical connector.  My speakers don't take optical audio - just six channels of analog audio.  I'd like to ask how to get around that, but it doesn't seem to fit on Server Fault, Stack Overflow or Super User.

Where would I ask about home audio setup?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42373/what-sites-are-currently-missing-from-the-trilogy

Comment: @Jon - it's not that it's young, it's that it's dead (nothing since October 14th 2009).

Comment: This could probably be adapted into a [hardware recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) question, if you looked for a specific piece of hardware to fulfill this request.

Answer (score 4):

You might get results at Super User, but be prepared for it to be closed.

For a while you might be better off posting on `home4film.com` which was a Stack Exchange (1.0) site, but it's long since gone.