# Which Stack Exchange site is suitable for home theater questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45663/where-would-i-ask-about-home-audio-setup) got sort of halfway to answering my question, but there have been a lot of changes to the Stack Exchange network in the past 2 years and some of the links referred to in there no longer work. Basically I want a place to ask questions like, say, "What remote should I buy if I have components x, y, z? or "How do I optimize my living room setup?" Does Stack Exchange have a site for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such site yet, but [Home Theater](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2274/home-theater) is a proposed site on area 51, so if this important to you, commit to it...

Comment: HT is dead. Long live [HT&A](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59720/home-theater-audio).

Comment: @CeesTimmerman HT&A is also dead :/

Comment: Both deleted. Utterly useless. Come on, StackExchange...

Comment: @MGOwen - sites fail because they don't have a community behind them.

Comment: That's fine: if a niche is too small, we don't need a separate site for it. But, obviously, **we still need a place to ask and answer those questions**. Right now, home theatre questions are deleted as off-topic from every stackexchange site, and the proposal to have a home theatre site has been deleted. That's pretty useless, if you think about it.